# I've got error message : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'dict' in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created new model in my django rest freamework app and I've got this error message :

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'dict'`

here is the error screenshot:
[image: error screenshot]

I can't understand what's the problem?

Here is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class TblUserAccounts(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    alias_username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_user_accounts'
        ordering = ['uid']


class TblUserDetails(models.Model):
    detail_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    useraccount = models.ForeignKey(TblUserAccounts, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name=TblUserAccounts.uid)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    record_time = models.DateTimeField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(TblUserAccounts, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name=TblUserAccounts.uid, db_column='creator')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_user_details'
        ordering = ['record_time']


class TblUserPassword(models.Model):
    id_password = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    useraccount_id_pwd = models.ForeignKey(TblUserAccounts, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name=TblUserAccounts.uid, db_column='useraccount_id_pwd')
    salt = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    record_time = models.DateTimeField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(TblUserAccounts, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name=TblUserAccounts.uid, db_column='creator')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_user_password'
        ordering = ['record_time']
```

Of course you should know that I'm new to Python programming.

I guess that the problem is in `TblUserDetails` model but I don't know what is it?

Thanks a lot for your attentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to test it I can really only throw a shot in the dark. Doing some reading though, I think the issue is what you use for `related_name`. Try the following:

```
class TblUserDetails(models.Model):
    detail_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    useraccount = models.ForeignKey(TblUserAccounts, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='TblUserAccounts.uid')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    record_time = models.DateTimeField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(TblUserAccounts, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='TblUserAccounts.uid', db_column='creator')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_user_details'
        ordering = ['record_time']
```

Note you will need to do this fix for `TblUserPassword` as well if this is the issue.

I think `related_name` shouldn't point to the attribute of another class but it is just a name field:

> [ForeignKey.related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
>
> The name to use for the relation from
>   the related object back to this one. It’s also the default value for
>   related_query_name (the name to use for the reverse filter name from
>   the target model). See the related objects documentation for a full
>   explanation and example. Note that you must set this value when
>   defining relations on abstract models; and when you do so some special
>   syntax is available.
>
> If you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set
>   related_name to '+' or end it with '+'. For example, this will ensure
>   that the User model won’t have a backwards relation to this model.
>
> ```
> user = models.ForeignKey(
>     User,
>     on_delete=models.CASCADE,
>     related_name='+', )
> ```

Let me know if this isn't the issue and I will see if I can find something else.